# Can I record a zoom meeting without attending?

Tags: screen-recorder, zoom-meeting

I mostly just want to use this for talks I cannot attend, but is there a way to record a zoom meeting without having to be present at the particular time.

Answer (score 1):

From a [recent Zoom blog post](https://blog.zoom.us/wordpress/2020/06/11/improving-our-policies-as-we-continue-to-enable-global-collaboration/):

> We do not have a backdoor that allows someone to enter a meeting without being visible.

So it is not possible to even view a Zoom meeting without being a participant, let alone record that meeting.

Answer (score 0):

**No** only the current host of a zoom meeting can record it.

*And honestly I wouldn't like anybody not participating in my meeting to record it. The correct way is to notify the organizer you can't attend and ask for the recording.*